# htaccess rewrite rule to external domain if query is with www

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

```
www.example.com
```

to

```
anotherdomain.com
```

Calls to example.com (without **www.**) should NOT be affected on this.
Normally this would be easy, but the special thing about this is that I want to execute the same script on a bunch of domains, so I can't put the specific domain-name inside the rewrite-rule.

Do you have any ideas how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why did you tag this with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://anotherdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```